# How to overload the << operator based on a method display already defined?

Tags: operator-overloading

I would like to overload the << operator for my class from a method display already defined. I get an compiler error of no match for operator <<.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:

  MyClass()
  {}

  ostream& display(ostream& out) const
  {
    out << "Display message" << endl;
    return out;
  }

  ostream& operator<< (ostream& out) const
  {
    ostream& output = display(out);
    return output;
  } 
};

int main()
{
  MyClass C1;
  cout << C1 << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Although  `C1.display(cout);` woks without problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `operator<<` as a **member function** of `MyClass`. Therefore, you must call it like member functions are called (object on the left, parameter on the right), like this:

```
C1 << cout;
```

But that doesn't seem to be what you want. You probably want to be able to call it like this:

```
cout << C1;
```

In that case the function can't be a member of `MyClass`. It would have to be a member of `cout`, **or** a *free function* (outside any class). And in this case it *must* be a free function because you can't change the definition of `cout`.

So, to declare `operator<<` as a free function, it needs to have two arguments (left-hand-side and right-hand-side):

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const MyClass& c) { ... }
```

Now you can call it with an `ostream` on the left and a `MyClass` object on the right, like this:

```
cout << C1;
```